# Can I specify an instance of a test class when using a JUnit5 launcher

Tags: dependency-injection, junit5

I would like to programmatically launch JUnit5 tests not on a class but on a specific instance of the class so I can perform dependency injection through the class's constructor.

I can launch execution on a class with:

```
launcher.execute(request().selectors(selectClass(MyTest.class)).build());
```

Is there a way to instead launch it on, for example, `new MyTest(someParameter)`?

Comment: You can use a Jupiter extension for that purpose, eg https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-test-instance-post-processing

Comment: @johanneslink Once I create the extension, how do I execute the tests in the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Jupiter extension for this purpose. Either `TestInstanceFactory` or `TestInstancePostProcessor` look like good candidates:

```java
class CreateMyTestExtension implements TestInstanceFactory {

    @Override
    public Object createTestInstance(TestInstanceFactoryContext factoryContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws TestInstantiationException {
        String param = "a string"; // Get it from wherever
        return new MyTest(param);
    }
}


@ExtendWith(CreateMyTestExtension.class)
class MyTest {

    private final String param;

    MyTest(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    @Test
    void aTest() {
        System.out.println("param = " + param);
    }
}
```

You can then run your test through the IDE or Gradle or Maven or use the standard code for launcher as suggested in the question:

```
launcher.execute(request().selectors(selectClass(MyTest.class)).build());
```

The open question is: Where does `param` come from? Depending on the answer to that you may have to use additional configuration parameters. Those can be set for a discovery request during launching and queried from the extension context: `extensionContext.getConfigurationParameter("param1")`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is for an autograder that will be running student-written tests against multiple versions of instructor-written code (some deliberately buggy, some ostensibly correct). Is there a programmatic way of attaching the extension to the test class without annotating the source code?

Comment: Not really. Only globally through SPI. Maybe choose a different approach like subclassing the student test class and overriding a provider method.

Comment: You are the GOAT!